# unwanted pagenumber on titlepage

Tags: titles, page-numbering

For some reason the pagenumber 1 does not dissapear from the first page. I dont want the pagenumber to show at the content page, although i do want it to be counted as page nr.1 - this is showing correctly. However, no matter where i put the `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` it just wont reset the titlepage. What am i doing wrong?

here my  code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{
\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote} \bf}
{\end{quote}}

\title{ } 
 \thispagestyle{empty}
\author{}\\
}
\date{18.1.2018}


\begin{document} 
\let\cite\citep

\baselineskip18pt

\maketitle 
\cleardoublepage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newpage

\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{Abstract}
\include{plan}
\include{Methods}
\include{additional-data-2}

\bibliography{scibib6}
\bibliographystyle{aM2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{
\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote} \bf}
{\end{quote}}

\title{} 
\author{}
\date{18.1.2018}


\begin{document} 
\let\cite\citep

\baselineskip18pt

\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{Abstract}
\include{plan}
\include{Methods}
\include{additional-data-2}

\bibliography{scibib6}
\bibliographystyle{aM2}
\end{document}
```